# Unable to upload files to Microsoft Custom Translator

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am trying to upload documents in https://portal.customtranslator.azure.ai , but no matter what the documents never appear in my document overview. I am trying with PDF's of EU treaties e.g. these ones.

https://europa.eu/european-union/sites/europaeu/files/docs/body/treaty_establishing_a_constitution_for_europe_en.pdf

https://europa.eu/european-union/sites/europaeu/files/docs/body/treaty_establishing_a_constitution_for_europe_da.pdf

I have tried from both edge, chrome and FF same results. I get an indication that large files may take a long time. But no matter how long I wait nothing appears in the document overview.

Answer (score 1):

We are having problems processing pdf files at this time.  We hope to have this addressed in our next release.  We are also planning an update of the file uploading process that will allow better reporting on the progress of file uploads.